# express router - regex - semicolon separated list

Tags: regex, node.js, express

i' ve an express router which i want to accept a semicolon separated list. * should stand for 0 or more values, however it accepts only one or more in my case.

Here is my code:

```
App.get('/sth/((\\w+(\;\\w+)*))',
```

however it accepts only

```
/sth/aaa;bbb
/stg/aaa;bbb;ccc
/sth/aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd
...
```

, but not

```
/sth/aaa
```

.

How can i achieve my goal or what' s wrong with my regexp? Probably i miss just one trivial thing.

Thanks.

Comment: `/sth/\\w+(\;\\w+)*` this should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround or a solution would be something similar

```
App.get('/sth/((\\w+(;\\w+){0,}))',
```

As I experienced, express doesn't use the standard regexp, but it has its own implementation, and the * has a different usecase. It' d be nice to know how it' s treated, but to me it seems it gets everything from 1 to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
/sth/\\w+(;\\w+)*
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the same than the one i wrote.

Comment: @user2194805 No, it's not the same. Try it.

Comment: I tried. I meant it has the same result, however i don' t know how to get the value at your solution. For one element it' s not working, however now i know why (see below my solution).